# What is the most efficient way to display lots of data on a website?

Tags: json, database, optimization, web

I have an optimization question.
Lets say that I'm making a website, and it has a JSON file with 5,000 pairs (about 582 kb) and through the combination of 3 sliders and some select tags it is possible to display every value. So the time to appear between every pair is in microseconds.

My question is: If the website is also made to run on mobile browsers, where is it more efficient to have the 5000 pairs of data - in a JSON file or in the data base? and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am building a photo site with similar requirements and I can say after months of investigations and experimenting that there are no easy answer to that question. But I will try to give you some hints:

1. Try to divide the data in chunks, for example - if your sliders are selecting values between 1 through 100, instead of delivering exactly what the client selected, round up a bit maybe +-10 or maybe more, that way you can continue filtering on the client side without a server roundtrip. Save all data in client memory before querying.
2. Don't render more than what is visible on the screen, JSON storage and filtering is fast but DOM is very slow, minimize the visible elements.
3. Use 304 caching - meaning - whenever the client is requesting the same data twice; send a proper 304 response with etag. For example - a good rule of thumb here is to use something you know very easily, like the max ID in the database or so to see if any new data has been updated since the last call. If not, just send 304 and the client will use whatever he had the last time.
4. Use absolute positioning. Don't even try to use the CSS float or something like that, it will not work. Just calculate each position of each element. This will also help you to achieve tip nr 2 (by filtering out all elements that are outside of the visible screen). You can still use CSS transitions which gives nice animations when they change sliders.
5. You could experiment with IndexedDB to help with the client side querying but unfortunately the support in different browsers are still not good enough plus you hit the roof on storage, better to use the ordinary cache and with proper headings.

Good Luck!

Comment: Good answer and recommended strategies. I'm curious to find out how much of this "microsecond response time" needs to be honored. When there's a lot of data, and the goal is to deliver relevant result in an interactive manner, sub second is often more than enough. Treat this slider combo lookup app as auto-complete. We can schedule multiple timer events and cancel all the previous ones, so that when the user "slows down", a query is sent to the server, and an ajax response is displayed. I know this is not the point of this question, but how far off is it?

Comment: I agree that most people are used to about a second response time for an action but there are more and more research showing that the human brain is starting to switch context far quicker than one second. That means if you want the user's attention to stay on the actual task you should tryto get response times (including roundtrip to server, db, rendering and transfer) below 400ms which requires some voodoo when dealing with large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

A database like MongoDB would be good for this.  It still uses the JSON syntax for storage so you can use the values from the JSON file.  The querying is very fast too and you wouldn't have to parse the JSON file and store it in an object before using it.

Answer (score 1):

Given the size of the data (just 582Kb) I will opt for the Json file.

The drawback is you will have a penalty starting the app and loading the data in memory, but  then all queries will run very fast in memory as a good advantage.

You need to think about how much acceses will your app do to the database (how many queries) against load the file just once. And think if your main objective are mobile browsers or pcs.

For this volume of data I wouldn't try a database (another process consuming resources), just try how much resources (time, memory) are needed to load the JSON file.

If the data is going to grow... then you will need to rethink this, or maybe split your json file following some criteria.